# Bounding the zeroes of a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials

I am reading [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.3969.pdf) paper which resolves the famous Kadison-Singer problem.
Recalling Definition 5.3 We say that $z\in R^m$ is *above* the roots of the polynomial $p(x_1,\cdots, x_m)$ (denoted as $z\in Ab_p$) if $p(z+t)>0,\forall t\in R^m_+$.

Now consider a univariate real rooted polynomial $p$, with positive leading coefficient. If $y>maxroot(p)$, then clearly $y\in Ab_p$, because $p(y+t) = \prod_i(y-\lambda_i+t) > 0, \forall t \geq 0$.

It turns out that the converse is also true(see the paragraph following the definition, where this fact is used, see also [this](http://www-cse-public.s3.amazonaws.com/ugrad/thesis/KuikuiLui.pdf), section 8.3, page 36). **How to prove this**? My reasoning is the following:

Let $\lambda_1\geq\cdots\geq\lambda_n$ are the roots of $p$. After appropriate scaling we can assume that the leading coefficient is 1, so

$p(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n(x-\lambda_i)$. Let $y\in Ab_p$. This means

$p(y+t) = \prod_{i=1}^n(y-\lambda_i + t) > 0, \forall t\geq 0$

Now suppose that $\exists r\in[n]$ such that $\lambda_1\geq\cdots\lambda_r>y>\lambda_{r+1}\geq\lambda_n$.
Now the first $r$ term in the factorisation, corresponding to the largest $r$ root is of the form $(-ve +t)$, and the remaining $n-r$ terms are of the form $(+ve + t)$. Now it is clear that is we choose sufficiently small non negative number as $t$, then   $p(y+t)<0$, when $r$ is odd, a contradiction.

But the above argument does not hold true when $r$ is even.

Comment: Good point, all the polynomials considered in the paper  has positive leading coefficient. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r$ is even, then $r\ge 2$, so $\lambda_2>y$. Now you can find $t$ such that $\lambda_1 >y+t>\lambda_2$ so that $p(y+t)<0$.

Comment: Nice solution, this works irrespective of parity of $r$. I do not need to make all the leading factors negative, just making an odd number of them negative will do.